# Question about PCA data recovery equation

Tags: pca, svd, linear-algebra

In PCA , consider a 4 x 3 data matrix ( 4 examples each with 3 features ). After getting the 3 eigenvectors (a/b/c) and projecting data on the first 2 vectors, the equation looks like this :

[ first 2 eigen vectors transposed ] x [ data set transposed ] = [ data projected ]

so the first example in the data after being projected would consist of:

$$[a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + a_3x_3]\\
[b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + b_3x_3]
$$

On recovering data the equation looks like this:

[first 2 eigen vectors] x [projected data] = [original data set]

so that the first example consists of:

$$
a_1[a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + a_3x_3] + b_1[b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + b_3x_3]\\
a_2[a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + a_3x_3] + b_2[b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + b_3x_3]\\
a_3[a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + a_3x_3] + b_3[b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + b_3x_3]
$$
My question is how is this equivalent to what the original example looked like $[x_1 x_2 x_3]'$? I know that unit vectors will cancel each other but the equation will be like

$$
a_1[a_1x_1] + b_1[b_1x_1]\\
a_2[a_2x_2] + b_2[b_2x_2]\\
a_3[a_3x_3] + b_3[b_3x_3]
$$

giving :
$$
x_1 + x_1\\
x_2 + x_2\\
x_3 + x_3
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $V$ is the matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors and $x$ is a 3-element column vector, then the transformed vector is given by

$$
x' = V^{T}x
$$

To recover the original vector, you would use

$$
x = Vx'= V[V^{T}x] = V[V^{-1}x] = [VV^{-1}]x = x
$$

But note that in your example, since you only projected $x$ onto the first two eigenvectors, you can not, in general, recover the original vector. You would need to project $x$ onto the full set of eigenvectors for it to be reversible (assuming there are no redundant eigenvectors).